# Cauchy-Euler equation

Tags: calculus

Can the dimension of solution space of a Cauchy-Euler equation defined on interval containing 0 be greater than the order of the differential equation?
For example, for $x^2y'' + 4xy' + 6y = 0 $ what should be dimension of solution space?

Comment: What do you mean by dimension

Comment: dimension of vector space formed by solutions of given equation

Comment: Would it not be infinite? As the  set of  general solution is a subset of all twice continuously differentiable functions.

Comment: dimnsion is defined to be number of independent solutions of given equation. It cannot be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot, as a cauchy euler equation is of the form $a_nx^ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+...+a_0y=0$, resulting in a polynomial of degree $n$, which can have at most $n$ roots, giving, at most $n$ independant solutions.

(Note $y^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $y$)

To do your example, let $y=x^n$, then $y'=nx^{n-1}$, and $y''=n(n-1)x^{n-2}$, substitute this into our ODE and we get:

$x^2n(n-1)x^{n-2}+4nx(x^{n-1})+6x^n=0\Rightarrow x^n(n(n-1)+4n+6)=0$, since we want a non zero solution, we assume $x^n\neq 0$, $\forall x$.

Thus we have: $n(n-1)+4n+6=0\Rightarrow n^2-n+4n+6=0\Rightarrow n^2+3n+6=0$

Thus: $n=-\frac{3}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}i$

So: $y(x)=Ax^{-\frac{-3}{2}}\cos(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}\ln(x))+Bx^{-\frac{-3}{2}}\sin(\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}\ln(x))$.

Comment: Can you please explain what are the 2 roots of my expamle?

Comment: I've edited, explaining the solution to your problem

Comment: If you have any queries, such as the seemingly random $\ln(x)$'s that appear in the solution, google cauchy euler equations and go on the wikipedia link, and look at the part about complex roots.